# Mono vs .NET mscorlib.dll | "method not found"

Tags: wine, mono

This case involves an application I am designing. This is the thrown exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.MissingMethodException: Method >'HashHelpers.IsWellKnownEqualityComparer' not found.

I am running into this error when attempting to run a .NET Framework 4.6.1 application through Wine. I found this:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,de3ba4873d4ad06a,references

...and it led me to **mscorlib.dll**. I checked, and there might be a certain difference between .NET's .dll and Mono's. Anyway, the application is trying to use Mono's .dll and not the .NET version (which might be obvious after a second or two).

It seems the particular solution is to build the application through Mono if having cross-platform function is a priority. Though, if someone didn't have the source code to the application, is there another solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was sort of simple.

#### The mistakes were:

I had mscoree.dll overwritten in **winecfg** *when* installing the .NET Frameworks. Also, I had Mono installed on the Wine prefix during the installation of the Frameworks.

#### Conclusion

*Not* doing these things a second time around resulted in the application working. I also needed to launch it using the *wineconsole*, if that's worth mentioning (it was a console application after all).